# is `git diff` able to apply diff to the current working tree?

Tags: git, diff, patch

I have a set of commits, say from commit A to commit Z. That set alters set of files in the repository. That is like development history of the feature with a bunch of tries and failures.

Now I want clean up the history, reduce number of commits and remove wrong attempts from the history. I want to leave my current development branch untouched and create clean history in another branch called for example `feature-rc1`. Later this branch will be merged into upstream repository.

So my plan is to take all changes made to some file `file1.cpp` and apply those changes to the working tree of `feature-rc1` branch. Then I will do the same with `file2.cpp` and `file3.cpp`. Then I commit changes and continue with another files and commits. So my basic operation will look like this:

```
git diff A Z -- file1.cpp >temp.diff
patch -P1 <temp.diff
git diff A Z -- file2.cpp >temp.diff
patch -P1 <temp.diff
git diff A Z -- file3.cpp >temp.diff
patch -P1 <temp.diff
git commit -a -m "commit"
```

My question is if it's possible to avoid using temporary diff files and external utilities such as `patch`? It would be great if `git diff` have built-in ability to apply diff result to the current working tree or if there is another git command with the same functionality.

**Update:** I think it is possible to avoid temporary files like this:

```
git diff A Z -- file1.cpp | patch -P1
```

But it would be great to avoid `patch` too:

```
git diff A Z -- file1.cpp | git ????
```

What could be there in place of ????

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about squashing commits?

Comment: Yes, this is squashing but on the per-file basis.

Comment: The command you are looking for is `git apply`.  (See also `git am` but `am` is for complete commits, rather than individual files.)  As already noted, squashes may be more appropriate (and/or `git cherry-pick -n`).

Comment: @torek: thank you. I think `git apply` is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best answer to my question was provided in comment by @torek.
And the answer is `git apply` command which can apply `git diff`'s output to the working tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply change syou should use the `git format-patch` command to generate the patches and then use the `git apply` to apply them to the desired branch/project.

[image]

Once you have the patches use the `git am` or `git apply` to add the patches to the desired branch/project.

---

> ***`git-apply`*** - Apply a patch to files and/or to the index
>   ***`git-am`*** - Apply a series of patches from a mailbox

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this this via diffing and patching, but this is really a better case for `git rebase -i`.

If `A..Z` is the range of commits you want to work with, use `git rebase A^ Z`, then switch all the lines to `edit`, and use commands such as `git reset <files>` and `git checkout -- <files>` to preserve only the changes you want.

I would then do a second pass of `git rebase -i` to do any necessary squashing, if it wasn't obvious what to do the first pass.

Comment: Yes, I know about interactive rebase. But it has two caveats in my situation:

1. It replaces existing history with the new one (not sure if it's possible to not replace existing history)

2. It is manual procedure. I instead want to create a shell script to be able to produce RC1, RC2 etc

Comment: Er, you're replacing the history with any other method too ... the old commits are still visible in the reflog though.